# Given top left and bottom right points, how can I find all points inside a rectangle?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, geometry, shapes

I am trying implement an excel-like click+drag feature where the user clicks on a cell and drags.  When the user stops dragging, I am able to calculate the top left corner and the bottom right corner of the rectangle.  I can also easily calculate the length, height and area of the rectangle, but how do I calculate the coordinates inside the rectangle?

Comment: Use two loops, an outer loop going from x1 to x2 and a nested inner loop from y1 to y2? Actually, I'm not sure what you mean by "the coordinates inside the rectangle"...

Comment: nested two loops are enough, but the real question is:  Why do you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
for i = left_edge to right_edge
    for j = top_edge to bottom_edge
        add [i, j] to list of points inside rectangle
```